# Prove that $G$ must be cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group, assume that for any pair of subgroup $H, K$ of $G$ either $H\subseteq K$ or $K\subseteq H$. Prove that $G$ must be cyclic.

---

Suppose $a$ is maximum in $G$. Let $\langle a\rangle =H$ and $\langle b\rangle =K$. If $H\subseteq K$, then it is a contraction since $a$ is maximum. If $K\subseteq H$, then $b=a^n\in H$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$, hence $H$ is cyclic which implies that $G$ is cyclic.

---

Can anyone check the proof valid or not? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum"?

Comment: @OnceUponACrinoid $a$ is the maximum generator.

Comment: Could you spell it out for us dolts, what's a maximum generator?

Comment: A proof along your lines works fine. The explanation is not optimal.  Let $a$ have maximal order. Suppose the group $H$ generated by $a$ is not all of $G$. Then there is a $b$ which is in $G$ but not in $H$. And now we quickly get a contradiction.

Answer (score 6):

I think you have the right idea and are simply expressing it in an unclear way. To use basically the same structure as you are and the same proof method, one might write it as:

> Let $a$ be such that $\langle a \rangle$ is never strictly contained in $\langle b \rangle$ for any $b$. If we let $H=\langle a \rangle$ and $K=\langle b\rangle$ for some $b$, then we have that either $H\subseteq K$ or $K\subseteq H$. However, given that we chose $a$ such that $\langle a\rangle \not\subset \langle b \rangle$ for any $b$, we can assume that $K\subseteq H$, implying that $a^n=b$. Given that this holds of any $b$, we conclude that $a$ must generate the whole group, meaning the group is cyclic.

We might also consider justifying the first sentence (e.g. why such an $a$ exists). We can consider $a$ a maximal element in $G$ when ordered by the relation $a>b$ where $\langle a\rangle \supset \langle b\rangle$ - and every finite poset has to have a maximal element, meaning such an $a$ exists.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps one rewrite the proof along the following lines.

Let $a$ be an element of $G$ of maximal order, and let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a$.  We show that $H$ is all of $G$.

Suppose to the contrary that there is a $b\in G$ such that $b$ is not in $H$, and let $K$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $b$. It is clear that $K$ is not a subset of $H$. So $H$ is a subset of $K$, necessarily proper. This contradicts the maximality of the order of $a$.

Comment: Because $G$ is cyclic, then $G\cong\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Comment: @Simple: Yes, the group turns out to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for some $n$, but that fact is not used in the argument.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $G$ is not cyclic, so let $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ be the set of generators and let $H_i=\langle a_i \rangle$ where $i\in \{1, \dots n\}$.

Now by hypothesis, we will get $$H_{i_1}\subseteq H_{i_2} \dots \subseteq H_{i_n}=\langle a_{i_n}\rangle$$ and this implies that $a_{i_n}$ generates $G$ and thus cyclic which is a contradiction. $\hspace{2cm} \blacksquare$